# Creating coordinate tuples with numpy using two 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

How can I get the following 2D array of tuples using numpy?

```
ab = [[(1,a), (2,a), (3,a), (4,a), (5,a), (6,a)],
      [(1,b), (2,b), (3,b), (4,b), (5,b), (6,b)],
      .
      .
      [(1,f), (2,f), (3,f), (4,f), (5,f), (6,f)]]
```

Comment: `itertools.product`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Instead of an NxN array of 2-tuples, you should rather create an NxNx2 array.

If you do that, you can use broadcasting assignment to achieve the array you want:

```
x = np.arange(6)      # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = np.arange(6, 12)  # [a, b, c, d, e, f]

out = np.zeros((len(x), len(y), 2))

out[..., 0] = x           # values are repeated for each row
out[..., 1] = y[:, None]  # values are repeated for each column
```

Comment: This does not work, if we assume that the `a, b, ...` are actually characters. Then you have to make them into a `tuple`to be able to store it in a `numpy` array.

Comment: Just change the `dtype=object`

Comment: To clarify a little more - This replaces the tuples with 2 element arrays. So you could say it's a 2D array of 2 element arrays, rather than a 2D array of tuples. The rest of the code is about python array slicing, which is [nicely explained here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Python provides a lot of ways to do this. You can do something like:

```
[[a0, b0] for a0 in a for b0 in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

A cartesian product will give you all of your combinations. You can then sort that list by the second key (letters), then re-nest it using a list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

out = list(itertools.product(a,b))
out.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

nested = [out[x:x+len(a)] for x in range(0, len(out), len(a))]
```

That will give the following nested list:

```
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'a'), (6, 'a')],
 [(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'b')],
 [(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'c')],
 [(1, 'd'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'd')],
 [(1, 'e'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'e')],
 [(1, 'f'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'f'), (4, 'f'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'f')]]
```

If you'd rather store it as a numpy array instead of creating a nested list, you would most likely want it as a 6x6x2 as opposed to a 2D array. You can do that with `np.array(out).reshape(6,6,2)`